# Azure Durable Functions "Not Found"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to run the Microsoft durable functions sample. [The article is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-install). When I run the functions project (C#, Visual Studio) it appears to launch fine, the CLI spins up and I get the Host Initialised and the two start URLs listed.

```
Http Functions:

        HttpStart: http://localhost:7071/orchestrators/{functionName}

        HttpSyncStart: http://localhost:7071/orchestrators/{functionName}/wait
```

However, when I navigate to a function to start it, it tell me "Not Found" e.g. through:

> http://localhost:7071/orchestrators/E1_HelloSequence

I get "Not Found":

```
[30/05/2018 21:17:40] Executed HTTP request: {
[30/05/2018 21:17:40]   "requestId": "9b82e4b2-c0df-4cf4-a191-ce7d7709d30f",
[30/05/2018 21:17:40]   "method": "GET",
[30/05/2018 21:17:40]   "uri": "/orchestrators/E1_HelloSequence",
[30/05/2018 21:17:40]   "authorizationLevel": "Anonymous",
[30/05/2018 21:17:40]   "status": "NotFound"
[30/05/2018 21:17:40] }
```

Any idea why this most basic of samples if giving me such a headache? I have tried many different combinations, all to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a `GET` request, while `HttpStart` is defined as `POST` in the samples. Either change your request, or add `GET` to `function.json`.

Comment: Thanks - just figured this out 2 seconds before you answer came in :)  Will leave this here to save others the headache!